# using sklearn pipeline with xgboost and onehotencoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have a pipeline in sklearn like this:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import xgboost as xgb

pipe = make_pipeline(OneHotEncoder(drop='first'),xgb.XGBRegressor())
```

My data comprises of 2 columns that are categorical in X:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
```

So X_train looks like this:

```
array([['Bob Dylan', 'WMQ'],
       ['James Doke', 'WMQ'],...
```

and y_train is a numeric array.

Now I want to use GRIDsearchCV with my pipeline:

```
gbm_param_grid = {
    'xgbregressor__colsample_bytree': [0.3,0.7],
    'xgbregressor__n_estimators': [50],
    'xgbregressor__max_depth': [2, 5]
}

grid_mse = GridSearchCV(pipe,param_grid=gbm_param_grid,scoring="neg_mean_squared_error",cv=4,verbose=1)
```

And I fit into the data:

```
grid_mse.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

And get this strange error:

```
xgboost.core.XGBoostError: [18:35:22] C:\buildkite-agent\builds\buildkite-windows-cpu-autoscaling-group-i-0cec3277c4d9d0165-1\xgboost\xgboost-ci-windows\src\data\array_interface.h:135: Check failed: typestr.size() == 3 || typestr.size() == 4: `typestr' should be of format <endian><type><size of type in bytes>.
```

What am I making wrong here ?

Comment: What version of XGBoost do you have? This error matches a bug which was reported in the [XGBoost Repository](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/6925). It should be fixed in versions above 1.4.2

Comment: xgb.__version__
`2.0.0`

Comment: If you run `OneHotEncoder(drop='first').fit_transform(X_train)` can you verify that the resulting array is fully numeric?

Additionally, could you provide some more logs prior to the failure?